# R function only on rows with no NA in specific column

Tags: r, na

I am trying to calculate the age from date of birth using `age_calc` from `eeptools` library:

```
data1$AGE <- floor(age_calc(as.Date(data1$BIRTH), units = "years"))
```

How can I make the function omit the rows where BIRTH has no value? Else it returns:

```
Error in if (any(enddate < dob)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `na.omit` to remove remove cases with NA values and create new table called `dataNoNA`. You'll have to perform following operations on `dataNoNA` as dimensions will be different from `data1`.

```
dataNoNA <- na.omit(data1)
dataNoNA$AGE <- floor(age_calc(as.Date(dataNoNA$BIRTH), units = "years"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the complete.cases function

```
birth<-complete.cases(data1$BIRTH)
data1$AGE <- floor(age_calc(as.Date(birth), units = "years"))
```

Comment: complete.cases only returns TRUE/FALSE for each row, so cannot follow with age_calc on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with tidyverse:

```
library(eeptools)
library(tidyverse)

# test data
data(stuatt)

# create NA's in a birth column
stuatt <- mutate(stuatt, birth = as.Date(birth_date, origin = "1960/01/01"))

stuatt <- group_by(stuatt, sid) %>%
      mutate(age = ifelse(is.na(birth), birth, 
                age_calc(as.Date(birth), units = "years")))
View(stuatt)
```

It will maintain all the values in your data frame - preserving the missing values.

HTH - James